# Error message in Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud

I'm new to IBM Bluemix. I faced this error message 'BXNUI0515E: The attempt to retrieve the spaces in the org failed because of a network connection problem. Try again later.'  Please Help me

Comment: have you tried the suggestions here: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/249741/retrieve-space-error-bxnui0515e-the-attempt-to-ret.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please double check if you have created a space in the current Region. This error often is received when you try to create an application or a service directly from the [Catalog](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/) for the first time without creating a space.

Answer (score 1):

1) Generally this issue is resolved creating application\service using the Bluemix catalog page directly: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/catalog/

2) you could use cf command line too:
create an application:

> - cf push your_app_name -b buildpack

create a service:

> - cf marketplace (shows Bluemix Catalog)
> - cf create-service service plan service_name

3) make sure that you have selected the correct organization\space in UI dashboard (this information is available from the user avatar in the upper right corner of the main Bluemix UI.)

4) if the issue is still there open a new ticket:
Use the Support Widget to open a ticket. It is available from the user avatar in the upper right corner of the main Bluemix UI.  After opening the support widget panel, select Get Help > Get In Touch, select the type of assistance you need, and then fill out the support form.
Use the Support Site 'Get Help' form. This form is available on a separate site that is made available for ticket submission when you cannot log into Bluemix and access the Support Widget.  Go to http://ibm.biz/bluemixsupport and fill in the support request form.