# Network error while setting up context mapping - IBM Bluemix

Tags: ibm-cloud, iot-context-mapping

I am getting network error every time and on every available device when I am trying to setting up `Context Mapping`, I am not sure if it is really due to Network as I am able browser any where else.

See the image for more details

[image: See the image for more details]

Comment: This Stack Overflow post might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36011457/error-message-in-bluemix

Comment: If that post does not help, please open a ticket with Bluemix Support so that they can look at your specific environment. See: https://ibm.biz/support_widget_instructions

Comment: Thank you @Bill Wentworth, I solved it myself by changing my region.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this error is to confirm that you are in proper region.

You can change the region from `Account > Region`. Set your region. Please see the image.
[image]